# Dynamically controlling IFrame size

Tags: html, iframe, widget

I have an IFrame that I am trying to make with dynamically controlled height and width, but it does not seem to be working.

For some reason, the IFrame just adds a scrolling bar when I want it to become bigger.  But how do I make the IFrame area itself become bigger?

Here is my current test page:
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/widget.php?type=hike&hike_id=108&width=200&height=450

You see the height and width params I added to the URL.  They are meant to control the IFrame, but all they seem to do is add/remove the scrolling bar.

FYI, the google map inside is also using the height and width.  I had meant the map and IFrame to increase and decrease in size in the same proportions.  How can I do that?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in PHP worked.

```
style="width:'.$width. 'px;height:'.$height.'px"
```